# How to correctly map a polygon type with postgis and hibernate-spatial?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-spatial

Assume I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  polygon GEOMETRY(POLYGON)
);
```

and entity class

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Foo {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private Polygon polygon;

}
```

I managed to save a Foo entity, however, I can't select it them from the database. I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PO"
```

Then, I added the following annotation on top of polygon field:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryType")
```

but it throws
 another exception saying that this type cannot be instantiated:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate Type: org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryType
```

Please note that I use 5.1.0.Final version for hibernate and hibernate-spatial.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

It seems `hibernate-spartial 5.x` knows how to handle JTS geometrical types natively so no type annotation required. Here is my working configuration.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

MySQL table...

```
CREATE TABLE `stuff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coordinates` point NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `coordinates` (`coordinates`)
)
```

JPA entity...

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
...

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "point")
private Point coordinates;
```

Hibernate dialect...

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect"/>
```

That's all but please note that my application runs within WildFly 10 which supplies additional runtime dependencies like the MySQL driver.

Answer (score 1):

You should try giving column name also

```
@Entity<br/>
@Table(name = "table_name")<br/>
public class Foo {<br/>

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "the_geom", nullable = true,columnDefinition="Geometry")
 private Geometry geom;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType",columnDefinition="Geometry")
private Polygon polygon;
}
```

you should also be aware that as of Hibernate Spatial 4.0-M1, only the Geometry type is specified to Hibernate, and hence the @Column annotation must set `columnDefinition="Geometry"`, and not Point or anything else. This may be fixed in the future.

With this anthology of modifications, I can finally write a Point to a database! The correct property specification is:

```
 @Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
 private Point centerPoint;
```

Also check with dialect in **hibernate.cfg.xml**

Add following line to **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
```

Comment: Thanks @Parth, but there is no `org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType` class in hibernate-spatial 5.x

Comment: Did you add proper dialect in persistence.xml file. `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>`

Comment: It can be `type="org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType"` also in it.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to hibernate-spatial 4.3 version. Please see my configuration below.

Entity column:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Polygon polygon;
```

The Polygon class can be found in `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom` package.

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
        <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hibernate dialect:

```
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

Comment: Interesting, I found out that hibernate-spartial 5.x actually knows how to handle JTS types natively so no type annotation required. I'll post my solution too.

Comment: I really did not want to downgrade because the application server within which I am running supplies hibernate 5.x and I would rather not fiddle with it.